# React - Autocomplete calling API onInputChange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I have a MUI Autocomplete component, and onInputChange I have a useEffect that fires, making an API call to query a very large list of cites, returning a subset of cities as `options` for the Autocomplete (`options={cities}`).

I was initially encountering a warning every time I selected a value, but got rid of the warning by adding the `freeSolo` prop to my autocomplete component. My problem now is that once I submit this form and store it in the database, when I retrieve that same record from the database and input the `values` into the autocomplete (`value={data.cities}`, I get the following error:

> MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `foo` for the select (name="example") component.
> Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
> The available values are `none`.

It's probably because `options` is now an empty array since nothing has been typed, and no API call has been made. How can I get rid of this warning? I have `values` but no `options` to check against (I don't really care to check honestly, I just need to get rid of the warning.

Here's an example of my Autocomplete:

```
        <Autocomplete
          multiple
          filterSelectedOptions
          freeSolo
          value={loadedValues ?? []}
          options={options ?? []}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => (typeof option === "string" ? option : option.Label)}
          onChange={(event, options) => {
            const values = options.map((option) => (typeof option === "string" ? option : option.Value));
            formik.setFieldValue(`${currentFilterFormString}.Values`, values);
          }}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          renderInput={(params) => {
            return <TextField {...params} />;
          }}
          renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
            tagValue.map((option, index) => (
              <Chip label={option.Label} {...getTagProps({ index })} key={index} disabled={false} />
            ))
          }
          onInputChange={(event, value) => {
            if (value === "") return;
            setChars(value);
          }}
          // this prop below doesn't help
          // isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.Value === value.Value}
        />
```

And my useEffect and API call:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (chars === "") return;
    onlookupInputChange();
  }, [chars]);

  const onlookupInputChange = async () => {
    const rsp = AudienceConfigAPI.lookupFieldValue(field.Field, chars);
    const data: SelectOption[] = (await rsp) as SelectOption[];
    setOptions(() => data);
  };
```

And here's a codesandbox that somebody else created for a very similar issue. If you open the console you'll see a similar error.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-2g3jq9?file=/index.js

Got that sandbox from this question [React - Autocomplete calling API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545423/react-autocomplete-calling-api)